# Is there anyway to generate random language shortcode without listing all language shortcodes?

Tags: c#, .net, random

Is there anyway to **generate random language shortcode** without listing all language shortcodes in **C#**?
I was thinking about creating list with all short codes and using random to choose the random one, but i need to do it **without using list** or **listing all languages**.

**Code that i am using:**

```
     var random = new Random();
     var languages = new List<string>{ "en","ak","cz","gu" }; //Many more.., i also need to somehow grab all of them from: https://www.science.co.il/language/Codes.php
     int index = random.Next(languages.Count);
     Console.WriteLine(list[index]);
```

Comment: The question is unclear. If you don't use a list of the valid country codes in your program you'll have to load them from another source. You can retrieve the list of countries from the cultures installed on your machine but that's not the full list of valid codes

Comment: Can you pick a random item from a list without the list? Well, no. There is no algorithm for generating these codes, since not all combinations of two letters are valid, so the list is unavoidable. At best you could avoid writing it out by storing it in a file or downloading it from an online service of some kind, but it would still be a list. (And if you are willing to download it, the machine-readable official version is [here](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/ISO-639-2_utf-8.txt)).

Comment: Using the list is the most obvious solution to this problem. Why don't you want to use the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to handle the 2-character ISO 639-1 cultures supported by .net, you can do this:

```
string[] names = 
    CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Select(culture => culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
    .Where(name => name.Length == 2)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(name => name) 
    .ToArray();
```

That gives the following list of names:

aa
af
ak
am
ar
as
az
ba
be
bg
bm
bn
bo
br
bs
ca
ce
co
cs
cu
cy
da
de
dv
dz
ee
el
en
eo
es
et
eu
fa
ff
fi
fo
fr
fy
ga
gd
gl
gn
gu
gv
ha
he
hi
hr
hu
hy
ia
id
ig
ii
is
it
iu
iv
ja
jv
ka
ki
kk
kl
km
kn
ko
ks
kw
ky
lb
lg
ln
lo
lt
lu
lv
mg
mi
mk
ml
mn
mr
ms
mt
my
nb
nd
ne
nl
nn
nr
oc
om
or
os
pa
pl
ps
pt
qu
rm
rn
ro
ru
rw
sa
sd
se
sg
si
sk
sl
sn
so
sq
sr
ss
st
sv
sw
ta
te
tg
th
ti
tk
tn
to
tr
ts
tt
ug
uk
ur
uz
ve
vi
vo
wo
xh
yi
yo
zh
zu

But note that this is not the full list of language codes.

If you want to include 3-character ISO names, remove the `.Where(name => name.Length == 2)`. Without that filter, the following names are also returned:

agq
arn
asa
ast
bas
bem
bez
brx
byn
ccp
ceb
cgg
chr
ckb
dav
dje
dsb
dua
dyo
ebu
ewo
fil
fur
gsw
guz
haw
hsb
jgo
jmc
kab
kam
kde
kea
khq
kkj
kln
kok
ksb
ksf
ksh
lag
lkt
lrc
luo
luy
mas
mer
mfe
mgh
mgo
moh
mua
mzn
naq
nds
nmg
nnh
nqo
nso
nus
nyn
prg
quc
rof
rwk
sah
saq
sbp
seh
ses
shi
sma
smj
smn
sms
ssy
syr
teo
tig
twq
tzm
vai
vun
wae
wal
xog
yav
zgh

(Let's not worry too much about the fact that TwoLetterISOLanguageName property actually includes a load of 3-character ones...)

Comment: I hope somebody's still slapping themselves over naming `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` that way. (Also, note that language codes and country codes are distinct things; "the full list of country codes" is part of its own standard.)